# What does "it does not pay" mean in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "it does not pay" mean in this sentence?

> Therefore, in spite of the fact that the basic question (“What is the force on Q due to q?”) is easy to state, **it does not pay** to confront it head on; rather, we shall go at it by stages.

I have done some search in internet, but didn't found whole phrase translation.

Comment: I edited your question to include the information from your comment and reopened it. Feel free to edit it if I haven't expressed your question correctly.

Comment: "it does not pay {to do something}" means that  doing {something} has some negative effect which is bad enough that {something} should not be done, and perhaps another approach should be taken.  *It doesn't pay to argue with your boss; even if you win the argument, you lose.*

Answer (score 1):

**It does not pay** means that the outcome does not have a positive effect that outweighs what it takes to get there.

It is, essentially, the same thing as **it isn't worth it**

**"Pay"** refers to a positive reward or profit from doing **"it"**, or in your example, **"[Confronting] it head on"** and that by **"[going] at it by stages"**, greater benefits will be achieved.